# Why does this NHibernate Linq query attempt to execute an insert statement?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am encountering a very strange issue I wonder if anyone has seen before. I have as part of my Save() method in a repository that it will search out and find each associated tag by it's name. There is a line in there that looks like this.

```
var tagRepo = (from t in tagRepository.Query() where t.Name == tag.Name select t).SingleOrDefault();
```

As soon as that line executes it throws this exceptions

```
GenericADOException: could not insert: [Core.Domain.Model.Tag][SQL: INSERT INTO [Tag] (Name) VALUES (?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]]
```

As far as I can tell or understand about what is happening here the Linq query shouldn't be executing an insert statement. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed it so I thought I would share the answer. The query in question was inside of another session. So there were these lines

```
using (var session = GetSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
```

Creating a session and a new transaction. After that the call the .Query() was actualy doing this.

```
return GetSession().Linq<T>().AsQueryable();
```

So it was trying to get another session inside my existing session and transaction. I moved the query and updates above the GetSession() and BeginTransaction() and everything worked properly.